# how to check if my testnet geth node has mined some ether?

Tags: mining, testnets

As per the instructions detailed in [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/how-to-enable-and-mine-testnet-morden), I've created an account:

[image]

and started running my geth node:

[image]

how can I check if it's mined any ether yet?

---

the answer of @lungj resulted in this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this from the `geth` console:

```
web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether")
```

It shows you the balance, in ether, of the account you are mining to. If it's not zero, either you've been sent some ether or you've mined some! Alternately, you can use this script which shows you the balance for all accounts:

```
function checkAllBalances() {
    var totalBal = 0;
    for (var acctNum in eth.accounts) {
        var acct = eth.accounts[acctNum];
        var acctBal = web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(acct), "ether");
        totalBal += parseFloat(acctBal);
        console.log("  eth.accounts[" + acctNum + "]: \t" + acct + " \tbalance: " + acctBal + " ether");
    }
    console.log("  Total balance: " + totalBal + " ether");
};
```

See also https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts

I don't think you need to unlock your account to execute this.

Comment: so- I tried it out- but it didn't work- did I do it right? put the attempt in an OP edit, is it right that I can just run that command in a second console window plugged into the same client with the following command (on OSX) `geth console --port "35555"`

Comment: Can you try replacing `eth.coinbase` with your Ethereum address (`0xd7a9...`) which is listed as your coinbase?

Comment: yep, did this one `web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance('0xd7a9a61a480d458a1181e0563b07f944df4489a6'),'ether').toString(10)` and it worked. can I query any address on there? even one of yours or anyones?

Comment: You sure can!  .